# Android SDK Eclipse Debug Mode

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How do you turn off or turn on debug mode in eclipse.  I'm not even sure I'm "in" debug mode, how do I find this out?

There is an attribute android:debuggable set to true in my manifest.  If i remove this, is "debug mode" turned off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to make your apk impossible to debug, then yes, `android:debuggable="false"` is enough.

In Eclipse you can choose to run your project in "debug mode", which means it will try to attach the debugger to your application. If the android:debuggable attribute is set to false, then it will fail.

Comment: Almost, but not *quite* true. If you have a pre-production device, you can still debug an app that has debuggable set to false.